# In Neovim which-key, how can I show the command instead of the description?

Tags: neovim, key-bindings

I'd like to make the label for each keymap the `keymap.rhs` instead of `keymap.desc` in the `folke/which-key.nvim` UI menu, even when they are both defined in the keymap. `keymap.rhs` is displayed by default when `keymap.desc` is not available with a sufficiently recent Neovim version. For example, I'd like to see "tabnew" here instead of "New Tab".

```
wk.register({
  ["<leader>"] = {
    t = {
      name = "tabs",
      o = { "<cmd>tabnew<cr>", "New Tab" },
    }
  }
})
```